# Get parent node with dojox.json.query

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I'm using `dojox.json.query` to get a node in a JSON struct like the one above:

```
{"data" : [ {
    "response" : [ {
        "key" : "value",
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2",
        "key3" : "value3",
        "key4" : "",
        "details" : [ {
            "key" : "",
            "key1" : "value11",
            "key2" : "",
            "key3" : "value33",
            "key4" : "",
            "details" : [ {
                "key" : "KEY",
                "key1" : "value111",
                "key2" : "value222",
                "key3" : "value333",
                "key4" : "",
                "details" : [ {
                    "key" : "",
                    "key1" : "value1111",
                    "key2" : "",
                    "key3" : "getThisOne",
                    "key4" : "",
                    "details" : [ {
                        "key" : "",
                        "key1" : "value11111",
                        "key2" : "",
                        "key3" : "value33333",
                        "key4" : "TARGET_1",
                        "details" : []
                    }, {
                        "key" : "",
                        "key1" : "value111111",
                        "key2" : "",
                        "key3" : "value333333",
                        "key4" : "TARGET2_1",
                        "details" : []
                    } ]
                } ]
            } ]
        } ]
    } ]
} ]
}

var evaluator = dojox.json.query("..[?key='value']");
var jsonQuery = evaluator(data.response);
```

I wonder if I could get the object that contains the father value `getThisOne`, once I received one of his son's like `Target_1` or `Target_2`. Does anyone know how can i get it parent once there's lack of documentation on it.

Comment: What's the JSON looking like? Maybe you can use a different expression to get where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like this is one of the missing features from XPath inside JSONPath/JSONQuery. In other words: this is one of those times when you actually should have used XML instead. The more hierarchical your data is, the more XML benefits matter.

That said, you could try this selector: `"..[?key3='getThisOne']/[?key='value']"` to only get the objects that have a parent object with `key3` being `getThisOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to format your json according to store relathionship models ?

like using _reference: #idOfTheItem
and put all the items at level 0 in your json. That way you could build the hierarchy with _reference and use dojo stores to getParent() for example, or do queries against the store ?